# Using php to extract keyword pairs for SEO

Tags: php, regex, seo, title, keyword

I'm currently investigating some new ideas for long tail SEO. I have a site where people can create their own blogs, which brings pretty good long tail traffic already. I'm already displaying the article title inside the article's title tags.

However, often the title does not match well for keywords in the content, and I'm interested in maybe adding some keywords into the title that php has actually determined would be best.

I've tried using a script which I made to work out what the most common words are on a page. This works ok but the problem with this is it comes up with pretty useless words.

It's occurred to me that what would be useful is to make a php script that would extract frequently occurring pairs (or sets of 3) words and then put them in an array ordered by how often they occur.

**My problem:** how to parse text in a more dynamic way to look for recurring pairs or triplets of words. How would I go about this?

```
function extractCommonWords($string, $keywords){
  $stopWords = array('i','a','about','an','and','are','as','at','be','by','com','de','en','for','from','how','in','is','it','la','of','on','or','that','the','this','to','was','what','when','where','who','will','with','und','the','www');

  $string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/i', '', $string); // replace whitespace
  $string = trim($string); // trim the string
  $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/', '', $string); // only take alphanumerical characters, but keep the spaces and dashes too…
  $string = strtolower($string); // make it lowercase

  preg_match_all('/\b.*?\b/i', $string, $matchWords);
  $matchWords = $matchWords[0];

  foreach ( $matchWords as $key=>$item ) {
      if ( $item == '' || in_array(strtolower($item), $stopWords) || strlen($item) <= 3 ) {
          unset($matchWords[$key]);
      }
  }   
  $wordCountArr = array();
  if ( is_array($matchWords) ) {
      foreach ( $matchWords as $key => $val ) {
          $val = strtolower($val);
          if ( isset($wordCountArr[$val]) ) {
              $wordCountArr[$val]++;
          } else {
              $wordCountArr[$val] = 1;
          }
      }
  }
  arsort($wordCountArr);
  $wordCountArr = array_slice($wordCountArr, 0, $keywords);
  return $wordCountArr;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more details and some code (if you have) as to what have you tried and what exactly your problem is?

Comment: How familiar/comfortable are you with regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of including some code - here's another primitive adaptation that returns multi-word keywords of a given length and occurrences - rather than strip all common words it only filters those that are at the start and end of a keyword.  It still returns some nonsense but that is unavoidable really.

```
function getLongTailKeywords($str, $len = 3, $min = 2){ $keywords = array();
  $common = array('i','a','about','an','and','are','as','at','be','by','com','de','en','for','from','how','in','is','it','la','of','on','or','that','the','this','to','was','what','when','where','who','will','with','und','the','www');
  $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s-]+/', '', strtolower(strip_tags($str)));
  $str = preg_split('/\s+-\s+|\s+/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  while(0<$len--) for($i=0;$i<count($str)-$len;$i++){ 
     $word = array_slice($str, $i, $len+1);
    if(in_array($word[0], $common)||in_array(end($word), $common)) continue;
    $word = implode(' ', $word);
    if(!isset($keywords[$len][$word])) $keywords[$len][$word] = 0;
    $keywords[$len][$word]++;
  }
  $return = array();
  foreach($keywords as &$keyword){
    $keyword = array_filter($keyword, function($v) use($min){ return !!($v>$min); });
    arsort($keyword);
    $return = array_merge($return, $keyword);
  }
  return $return;
}
```

[run code](http://ideone.com/4BecyK) <sup>*on random BBC News article</sup>

---

The problem with just ignoring common words, grammar and punctuation though is that they still carry meaning within a sentence.  If you remove them you are at best changing the meaning or at worst generating unintelligible phrases.  Even the idea of extracting "keywords" itself is flawed because words can have different meanings - when you remove them from a sentence you take them out of context.

It's not my area but there are complex studies into natural languages and there is no easy solution - though the general theory goes like this:  A computer cannot decipher the meaning of a single piece of text, it has to rely on cross referencing a semantically tagged corpus of **related** material (which is a *huge* overhead).

Comment: I'll have to give this a go! Thanks!

Comment: @AmyNeville it's still fugly - does allow you to be a bit more trigger happy with the array of "common" words to try and get more meaningful results. :) - possibly even go as far as tweak the parameters `$len` and `$min` based on the length of the article being looked at?